# How do I show the results found in an if then statement?

Tags: bash, shell-script

So, what I am trying to do is look for a set of files, and then have it echo which ones it has found. For example, this is what I have

```
    #!/bin/bash

    LaunchDaemon="LaunchDaemon.plist" 
    launchAgent="LaunchAgent"
    mobileLaunchDaemon="MobileDaemon.plist"
    mobileAgent="MobileAgent"

    if [ -f "$LaunchDaemon" ] || [ -f "$launchAgent" ] || [ -f "$mobileLaunchDaemon" ] || [ -f "$mobileAgent" ]
then
    echo "<result>Found</result>"
else
    echo "<result>Not Found</result>"
fi
```

So, this will tell me if it can find any of them, but it won't tell me which one it is finding. I created another with `elif` statements inside, which works sort of, but if it finds the first one, it stops there and won't tell me if the others are there as well. So, I hope this makes sense, I'm just trying to find a way to display which of the files have been found.

Comment: can't you use if..elif..else..fi statement ?

Comment: How about having separate if statements for each of the possible things and build the result string in a variable which is echoed out only in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split your `if` test into multiple

```
if [ -f "$LaunchDaemon" ]
then
  echo $LaunchDaemon found
elif [ -f "$launchAgent" ]
then
  echo $launchAgent found
elif [ ... 
  ...
else
  echo Not found
fi
```

type structure (fill in the blanks yourself.).

If you want to find all matches just do it as multiple tests, setting a variable to see if anything was found or not

```
found=0
if [ -f "$LaunchDaemon" ]
then
  echo $LaunchDaemon found
  found=1
fi
if [ -f "$launchAgent" ]
then
  echo $launchAgent found
  found=1
fi
...
if [ $found == 0 ]
then
  echo Not found
fi
```

Now sometimes we want to set a variable so we know which one was found.  This is common when trying to find a matching program or file (eg in the old days we might have had `/usr/lib/sendmail` or `/usr/sbin/sendmail` depending on the OS distribution, so we'd need to search to find it).

```
found=
for f in "$LaunchDaemon" "$launchAgent" "$mobileLaunchDaemon" "$mobileAgent"
do
  [[ -f "$f" ]] && found="$f"
done
```

Now we have `$found` pointing to a found entry and can test on that.

```
if [ -n "$found" ]
then
  echo Found: $found
else
  echo Nothing found
fi
```

The second loop can also find *all* versions with a minor change:

```
found=
for f in "$LaunchDaemon" "$launchAgent" "$mobileLaunchDaemon" "$mobileAgent"
do
  [[ -f "$f" ]] && found="$found $f"
done
```

The downside of this is that there may be a leading space in front, so we should remove that:

```
found="${found# }"
```

Comment: +1. BTW, a minor modification of that final `for` loop can be used to choose a file to use from one of several dirs - e.g. `for d in /etc/program /usr/share/program /usr/local/etc ~/.program ; do [ -e "$d/conf" ] && configfile="$d/conf" ; done; [ -z "$configfile" ] && echo "no config found" && exit 1` - the last one found will be used, so dirs are in order from lowest to highest priority.

Answer (score 1):

An array would be the best approach here

```
#!/bin/bash
#Store the filenames in an array, also less management overhead
arry=( "LaunchDaemon.plist" "LaunchAgent" "MobileDaemon.plist" "MobileAgent" )
#Optioinally if you wish to add one more file to check you could
#uncomment the below line
#arry+=("$1") #One more file added from the command line
for i in "${arry[@]}" #Iterate through each element using a for loop
do
 if [ -f "$i" ]
 then
  echo "<result> $i Found</result>" 
 else
  echo "<result> $i Not Found</result>"
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash
search_LaunchDaemon="LaunchDaemon.plist"
search_launchAgent="LaunchAgent"
search_mobileLaunchDaemon="MobileDaemon.plist"

for filex  in ${!search_*}
do
found=${!filex}
#echo  -e "${filex}=${!filex}"
#we remove the prefix "search_"
IFS="_" read part1 part2 <<< "${filex}"

if [[ -f $found ]];
then
echo "I have found ${part2}"
else
echo "${part2} not found!"
fi
done
```